# How can we isolate API urls in the frontend of a React App?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api

I just started learning React and I thought of making a simple app where I will have some API endpoints and the frontend will hit them with GET/POST requests.
But how can I hide those API urls from other users i.e anyone can open DevTools, find the API url and misuse it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't, they are always visible on every website

Comment: I have seen certain sites like that, but when I tried to hit the URL directly from the browser, it gave me an error, but it is working just fine with the web application.
What type of measure was it?

Comment: So they weren't hidden. You probably got an error because you didn't send cookies

Comment: Okay!! Now I get it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to hide API endpoints in the way you are suggesting. Security measures would have to be implemented in the back end in order to prevent misuse.

Comment: Can you please suggest some security measures, so that, even if someone have the API url, they won't be able to misue it, or in simple words, if the user copies the url and tries to hit it with from the browser directly from the address bar, he will get an error.

Comment: You could do a couple of things:  
  
Basic: Set up some form of user authentication, where you would require either a valid API key or token to be passed for example in the header of every request.  
  
A bit more advanced: Set up [CORS rules](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) and use a library like [helmet](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet) for further security.